# Best way to draw simple rectangle in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, drawing, rectangles

I am writing a little program in C++ with Qt.
I have a QGridLayout with 3*3 QWidget. In each QWidget, I have a QVBoxLayout.
Within that QVBoxLayout I need to put a certain number of black and white rectangles.

For now, I use QWidgets for these rectangle and I apply a background-color to get the white and the black ones.

I saw in the documentation something about a Rectangle class that is linked with QtQuick and I don't really want to go into that.

Thanks for your answers,

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with the layout and widgets unless you actually need interactive objects for each square. Just overload the `paintEvent` member of the widget you are using that contains the grid layout and use the `QPainter` object and call `fillRect`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have just tried to use QPainter. It seems to be a good idea but here, in order to display rectangle in a column, I would need to compute the exact position in pixel ?Is there a way to avoid doing that ?

Comment: No, there's no way to avoid that but the math is trivial

Answer (score 0):

To get an outline around a widget, use a `QFrame`.  Also `QLabel` subclasses `QFrame`.  There are a lot of examples of using QFrame in the documentation.

Hope that helps.